# Los datos llegan a la vista pero no se muestran en el Select

Tags: html, c#, razor

Estoy intentando hacer un filtro para unos **Distritos** que dependen de que **Provincia** sea seleccionado en un `select`, la provincia seleccionada la envió con ajax al controlador.

Las provincias y distritos los extraigo de unos archivos `.json` que tengo localmente.

***PROBLEMA***: Los Distritos seleccionados no se mapean en las vista a la hora de mapear.

***CODIGO***

Leo el texto de los archivos:

```
StreamReader readerProvincias = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoProvincias.json");
StreamReader readerDistritos = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoDistritos.json");
```

Leo los caracteres:

> Lee todos los caracteres desde la posición actual hasta el final de la secuencia [Documentación de Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0).

```
string jsonStringPr = readerProvincias.ReadToEnd();
string jsonStringD = readerDistritos.ReadToEnd();
```

Debido a que son varios modelos que se van a retornar a una sola vista decidí crear un modelo que en sus propiedades contendrían los demás modelos:

```
public class Selects
    {
        public Paises[]? Paises { get; set; }
        public Corregimientos[] Corregimientos { get; set; }
        public Distritos[] Distritos { get; set; }
        public Provincias[]? Provincias { get; set; }
    }
```

Siguiendo con el proceso, paso a **Deserializar**

```
Provincias[] provincias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Provincias[]>(jsonStringPr);
Distritos[] distritos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Distritos[]>(jsonStringD);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me trae todos los distritos existentes que son 80 en total.

Ahora toca filtrar los Distritos dependiendo de la Provincia seleccionada

***CONTEXTO***: Ejemplo de Provincias y Distritos

Provincia:

```
{ codigo: "7", ubicacion: "Los Santos" },
```

Si selecciono como Provincia en este caso **Los Santos** con código 7, tengo que buscar todos los Distritos (**Los Santos** tiene 7 Distritos) que en su código inicie con **7-** (Siete y un guion).

Por ejemplo:

```
{ codigo: "7-4", ubicacion: "nombre" }, 
{ codigo: "7-5", ubicacion: "nombre" },
...
```

Eso lo hago con el siguiente fragmento de código, funciona perfecto y me devuelve lo siguiente (Imagen):

```
var distritosSeleccionados = distritos.Where(x => x.codigo.Substring(0, 2) == codigoProvincia + "-").ToArray();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo los añado al modelo `Select` que voy a utilizar en la vista y los retorno

```
modeloSuper.Provincias = provincias;
modeloSuper.Distritos = distritosSeleccionados;

return View(modeloSuper);
```

**Tipo de datos retornados:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***PROBLEMA:***
El select no se llena con los Distritos encontrados

```
<select id="select-distritos" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected">Selecciona un Distrito:</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Distritos)
        {
            <option value=@item.codigo>@item.ubicacion</option>
        }
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se puede ver en la imagen el modelo si trae los Distritos y me trae los 7 que son los correspondientes a la Provincia que seleccione **(Los Santos)** pero el select aparece vacío.
El select de provincia por ejemplo ese si funciona perfecto.

Comment: O hay alguna otra alternativa para llenar el `select de Distritos` según la opción seleccionada del `select de Provincias`.

Comment: De casualidad podrías subir una réplica en GitHub, para revisar más a detalle tu código?

Comment: Hola @Daniel [GitHub](https://github.com/JoseMG-ux/GenerateXml23) aquí está el repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error se debe en que tu vista `ViewInfoEmisor` estas usando mvc y no estas enviando ningun dato para la vista `ViewInfoReceptor` por eso siempre llegaba null y no recibias ningun dato en la lista de distritos, tampoco estas usando Jquery, si quieres seguir usando c#, lo harias de esta manera

primero en tu vista de **ViewInfoEmisor** agregar el metodo post, tu vista quedaria mas o menos de esta manera. **Nota**: se pasan todos los datos que tienen la propiedad **name**, debe tener el mismo nombre en tu controlador

**name="codigo"**

```
<form method="post" asp-action="ViewInfoEmisor">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Provincia de la Sucursal:</label>
    <select id="select-provincia" class="form-control" name="codigo">
        <option selected>Selecciona una Provincia:</option>
       @* @{var count = "0";}*@
        @foreach (var item in Model.Provincias)
            {
            <option value="@item.codigo" selected>@item.ubicacion</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
     <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>
```

en tu controlador tendras dos metodos para `ViewInfoEmisor` , uno que sera el get, donde recibes todos los datos de tu provincia.

```
public IActionResult ViewInfoEmisor()
        {
            Selects modeloSuper = new();
            StreamReader readerProvincias = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoProvincias.json");
            string jsonStringPr = readerProvincias.ReadToEnd();
            List<Provincias> provincias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Provincias>>(jsonStringPr);
            modeloSuper.Provincias = provincias;
            return View(modeloSuper);
        }
```

y este que sera el mas importante, sera tu post, lo cual redireccionas los datos a la vista de **ViewInfoReceptor** usando `RedirectToAction`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ViewInfoEmisor(string codigo)
{
  return RedirectToAction("ViewInfoReceptor", new { codigo });
}
```

por ultimo tu controlador, solo le agregue el metodo, como consejo deberias especificarlos

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ViewInfoReceptor(string codigo)
{
    Selects modeloSuper = new();
    #region StreamReader
    StreamReader readerPaises = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoPaises.json");
    StreamReader readerProvincias = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoProvincias.json");
    //StreamReader readerCorregimientos = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoCorregimientos.json");
    StreamReader readerDistritos = new StreamReader("./json/CatalogoDistritos.json");
    string jsonStringPa = readerPaises.ReadToEnd();
    string jsonStringPr = readerProvincias.ReadToEnd();
    //string jsonStringC = readerCorregimientos.ReadToEnd();
    string jsonStringD = readerDistritos.ReadToEnd();
    #endregion
    List<Paises> paises = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Paises>>(jsonStringPa);
    List<Provincias> provincias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Provincias>>(jsonStringPr);
    IEnumerable<Distritos> distritos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Distritos>>(jsonStringD);

    List<Distritos> distritosSeleccionados = distritos.Where(x => x.codigo.Split("-")[0] == codigo).ToList();
    modeloSuper.Paises = paises;
    modeloSuper.Provincias = provincias;
    modeloSuper.Distritos = distritosSeleccionados;
    return View(modeloSuper);
}
```

en caso contrario si deseas usar JQuery, te recomiendo que uses onclick, pero iria en el button de la vista `ViewInfoEmisor` que seria mas o menos de esta manera, solo faltaria hacer la redireccion a la vista de `ViewInfoReceptor`

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        localStorage.setItem('progress-bar', '60%');
        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                url: `/Home/ViewInfoReceptor/`,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    id: $("#select-provincia option:selected").val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });

        }
    </script>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="submitForm()">Siguiente</button>
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funciono a la perfección, sin duda esto ya me solucionara muchos problemas en el futuro.

Comment: La recompensa te la da de una vez cuando acepto la respuesta?.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux de nada, fue un placer ayudarte, la recompensa no tengo idea, supongo que si, la verdad no sé

Answer (score 1):

Esto que te voy a decir no debe solucionar tu problema, solo es un método alternativo al que tienes para obtener los distritos de la provincia modificando la consulta **Linq**:

```
var distritosSeleccionados = distritos.Where(x => x.codigo.Split("-")[0] == códigoProvincia).ToArray();
```

Aquí se usa la **función Split** la cual recibe como parámetro el **caracter delimitador**(en tu caso un **"-"**) y **devuelve un arreglo de strings**. Por ejemplo si tienes el código **"7-4"**, al aplicar la **función Split** obtendrías un arreglo donde la primera posición sería **"7"**(código de provincia) y la segunda posición sería **"4"**(código del distrito), por tanto para acceder al código de provincia del arreglo obtenido accederás a la primera posición del arreglo(**[0]**).

Comment: Gracias por el dato, parecido al método `Split()` también en Js.